# prior distribution for iid gaussian, with a known variance

Tags: bayesian, normal-distribution, prior, posterior, sequential-analysis

I have been reading Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning by Bishop, and I have a question regarding the prior distribution of an iid Gaussian with known variance.

The relationship $\dfrac{n}{\sigma^2} + \dfrac{1}{\sigma^2_0} = \dfrac{1}{\sigma^2_n}$ is derived in the text. The derivation stems from the fact that you have Gaussian likelihood, coupled with a Gaussian prior. Hence, the posterior is also of Gaussian form.

In the relationship, variance is known, while the mean is unknown. I believe (and you correct me if this is wrong) $\sigma^2_0$ is the prior variance, $\sigma^2_n$ is the variance of the data set (?)

My question is: I thought the variance is known. Why are we solving this relationship? Or this can be used in sequential learning as the data are slowly trickling in (with known variance), we can use $\sigma^2_0$ as the prior variance. As the $n-$th data point comes in, $\sigma^2$ is the variance of the past $n-1$ data points, and your posterior variance is $\sigma^2_n$.

Please clarify this?

Comment: Can you give a pointer to where in Bishop you're seeing this (e.g., Chapter #/section/topic)?

Comment: This is in Chapter 2.3.6 (Bayesian inference for Gaussian), specifically equation number 2.142 (page 98 of the book)

Comment: After a careful read, $\sigma^2$ is the variance of each *observation* $x_i$, while $\sigma^2_N$ is the variance of the posterior distribution of *parameter* $\mu$ given $N$ observations. Similarly, $\sigma^2_0$ is the prior variance of the *parameter* $\mu$. So (using book notation where possible) Eq. 2.142 says $$\frac{1}{\mathbb{V}(\mu_N)} = \frac{1}{\mathbb{V}(\mu_0)} + \frac{N}{\mathbb{V}(X)}.$$

Not sure if that clears this up for you?

Comment: Thanks for this. I have a question about $\sigma^2$ being the variance of each observation $x_i$. Could this mean: the variance of the past observations together with the current $x_i$?